# No module named pyopendata.io

Tags: python-3.x

I just did a pip install of pyopendata using Python 3.5.1 (Anaconda distribution).
The install completed without errors. "import pyopendata" failed:

```
ImportError: no module named pyopendata.io
```

I can see the io module in github but it did not download.

Comment: downloading the tar file from github does include the io sub-module. I've posted this as an issue on the repository.